# comma not being removed as expected from string

Tags: c#

I have an MVC app which I need to store information into the database. I get a string value e.g. as

```
string a = "a,b,c";
```

I then split the string by removing the commas as

```
string[] b = a.Split(',');
```

Now before I save to database I have to add the comma back in and this is where I'm kind of stuck. I can add the comma however one gets added to the end of the string too which I don't want. If I do `TrimEnd(',')` it removes every comma. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please. I'm adding the comma back as:

```
foreach(var items in b)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},", items));
}
```

Please note I have to split the comma first due to some validation which needs to be carried out before saving to DB

The expected result should be for example

> a,b,c

In stead I get

> a,b,c,

Update - The below is the code I'm using In my MVC app after [Bruno Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37071304/4207709) answer

```
string[] checkBoxValues = Request.Form["location"].Split(',');
foreach(var items in checkBoxValues)
{
   if (!items.Contains("false"))
   {
       UsersDto.Location += string.Join(",", items);
   }
 }
```

Comment: `TrimEnd(',')` should only remove trailing commas, not all commas.  At what point are you using it?  In the `foreach` or after the `foreach`?

Comment: @juharr that's what I thought it does but it's removing every comma from the list

Comment: try my solution I have used `TrimEnd(',')` too, it works as you expect

Comment: @Code You really should show the exact code you are using instead of describing it.  That way we can reproduce your problem and tell you why it didn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: @juharr I've just updated my code

Comment: @juharr updated my solution using your exact code

Comment: Wait, do you need to filter out some of the values?  If so you can use Linq to do the filtering, then do the Join.  You shouldn't do the Join instead of a loop.

Comment: @juharr Yes I need to filter out all the `false` values from the string. Would it be possible if you can show me an example with LINQ please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you posted this is what I think you need

```
UsersDto.Location = string.Join(
    ",", 
    Request.Form["location"]
           .Split(',')
           .Where(item => !item.Contains("false")));
```

That will split the values in `Request.Form["location"]` on comma.  Then filter out items that contain "false" as a substring, and finally join them back together with a comma.

So a string like "abc,def,blahfalseblah,xyz" would become "abc,def,xyz".

Comment: This is spot on! Thank you and its a lot cleaner

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
string.Join(",", b);
```

This will add a ',' in between each item of your array

Comment: Please see my updated code.. I should get back `London, Cambridge` but instead I'm getting `LondonCambridge`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `String.Join` then?

```
var result = String.join(",", b); // a,b,c
```

Full document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

it can do

```
string[] checkBoxValues = Request.Form["location"].Split(',');
string s = "";
foreach (var items in checkBoxValues)
{
    if (!items.Contains("false"))
      {
        s = s + string.Format("{0},", items);
      }

}
UsersDto.Location = s.TrimEnd(',');
```